# How to set recyclerview's gap same(include the gap between screen border and the item )

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is it possible to make four gaps' width the same?
I tried to use ViewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener() in ItemDecoration.getItemOffsets(),but the view displays before the value returned,and the gap was 0.
[The gap image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn3LH.png)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does your parent layout have padding?

Comment: no.The recyclerview is in a relativeLayout (recyclerview -width:wrap_content,and center_horizontal in parent)

Comment: Make the parent Relative layout width as match_parent and take out center_horizontal

Comment: The parent RelativeLayout 's width is match_parent ,the RecyclerView's width is wrap_content and it's center_horizontal .

Comment: So the relativelayout doesn't have padding

Answer (score 0):

Yes, First you can set layout_margin on recycleview.
After set margin on recycleview raw.
It's work.

Comment: i have not demo. But you can set layout margit on recycleview first.
then go to recycleview raw file and set margine half of recycleview margin.